# Making a Telegram bot with Python with the `telebot` library

Tags: python, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telebot

I'm trying to make a telegram bot with python but when I import telebot library (I have installed  pyTelegramBotAPI  & telebot libraries), but some parts don't work, like `message_handler()`, `.reply_to()` and `.infinity_polling()`.

What could be causing this problem?

[image: obnoxious image]

```
import telebot  
import constant 
from datetime import datetime

BOT_TOKEN = constant.api_key
bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) 
def send_welcome(message): 
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?") 

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help']) 
def send_welcome(message): 
    bot.reply_to(message, "you can ask me datetime and hi to me and ask who am i and how am i") 

@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: True)
def javab(in_text):
    
    user_mess = str(in_text).lower()

    if user_mess in ('hi','hello','sup'):
        bot.reply_to(user_mess, "hi bro wtf do u want")
    if user_mess in ('time','what time is it?','time?'):
        now = datetime.now()
        date_time = now.strftime("%d/%m/%Y,%H:%M:%S")
        bot.reply_to(user_mess, str(date_time)) 
    if user_mess in ('who are u','who are you?','you?'):
        bot.reply_to(user_mess, 'non of your business , im hironside')
    if user_mess in ('how are u?','how are you?'):
        bot.reply_to(user_mess, 'im good')
    if user_mess in ('/stop'):
        return 'ok good bye'
    else:
         bot.reply_to(user_mess, 'go fly a kite')
print('bot is runnig ......')

bot.infinity_polling(5)
```

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: Probably the version of telebot you have installed does not have those functions and has changed it's API.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: the error message is clear. that method does not exist !

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have version problems maybe try this

```
pip uninstall pytelegrambotapi
pip install pytelegrambotapi
```

Pytelegrambotapi have a lot of Changes maybe you're using older version docs.